# drupal missing table `rules_config`

Tags: php, drupal

I have a missing table in drupal 7.3, table name `rules_config`, what are the soulution for restoring this table? do I need to find an sql query, and run it manually, or it should come with a module install?

Comment: Try disabling and re-enabling the rules config module. Sometimes that results in re-running the module install script.

Comment: Or (if disabling/re-enabling is not helping) try making some fresh drupal installation on some other server, install the module and get table definition from it. Then move it to site where that table is missing.

Comment: disable and uninstall module will delete alle table and data related to it , so get structure form install file or from new installation of drupal and restore it. Or the best solution is to restore a mysql backup if you have it ;)